# Warnings and Notices in EE6

Tags: control-panel

This actually started when I was upgrading a site from EE2. I got it to EE5 and started seeing some odd notices and warnings. So I upgraded to EE6 hoping to fix the issue, but the warnings persist, and I can't pin down the cause.

```
Notice
Trying to get property 'site_name' of non-object

ee/ExpressionEngine/Model/Template/TemplateGroup.php, line 174

Notice
Trying to get property 'site_name' of non-object

ee/ExpressionEngine/Model/Template/TemplateGroup.php, line 174

Warning
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ee/legacy/core/Exceptions.php:120)

ee/ExpressionEngine/Boot/boot.common.php, line 477
```

I've tried adding a second Super Admin to see if it was an issue with the legacy member account, but that wasn't it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you try to clear caches and try again?

Comment: Do you check 'exp_sites' table have the entry for your 'site_id'?

Comment: Yes. Cleared caches. No change. site_id, site_label, and site_name all have something. site_description is null, but that's common.

Comment: Can you try disabling extensions and seeing you still get those warnings?
`$config['allow_extensions'] = 'n';`
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/general/system-configuration-overrides.html#allow_extensions

If the warnings go away after that, then you can disable your extensions and add them back one by one until your find the culprit. 

Also for reference, what version of PHP are you running?

Comment: No change with disabling extensions. Still getting the warnings. Tried using PHP 7.2, 7.3, and 7.4. Host is InMotion. I've never had any trouble with the 20+ sites I've hosted with them.

Comment: If it helps, I don't see the error messages consistently. Only in the Template Manager when editing a tempate or if I initially change a system setting.

Comment: I have yet to be able to replicate this. Just to make sure I'm testing correctly, what version of 6 are you currently running?

Comment: EE 6.0.6. At this point, I'm thinking it's a server misconfiguration somewhere, since no one else is seeing these errors.

Comment: I'm getting them as well. Running under MAMP locally and on a dev environment hosted with Nexcess.

Comment: Every time I try and edit any template, I get all my template folders added to the `templates` folder, i.e. above `default_site`.

Comment: I've created a bug report: https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine/issues/1333